# Accessing previous steps in Wizard Form, Django

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I cannot get to jump to previous steps of WizardForm in django in any different way than the one showed in documentation

From the documentation we have that we can jump to previous steps through:

```html
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
   <button class="btn btn-outline-info" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Previous Step</button>
{% endif %}
```

However if I use the same button above the form, or try to emulate anything similar with HTML tag a and href, nothing seem to work.
I need something like that because I have implemented a breadcrumb above and I need every previous step completed, to be a link to that form

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the button was not usable above the form was that I was trying to place it outside the HTML tags:

```
<form></form>
```

Now for the rest of the question, I managed to change the breadcrumb to use buttons like

```
<button class="bs-wizard-dot" name="wizard_goto_step" value="classes"></button>
```

where in value I place the name of the form-wizard step, and the whole breadcrumb is inside the form as well, as explained above.